# What is the meaning of Type field on PermissionSet standard object in Salesforce?

Tags: permissions, security, permission-sets, system-permissions, permission-set-groups

[Documentation page about permission set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm) provides a limited information about Type field.

```
Type:  reference
Properties: Filter, Group, Nillable, Sort
Description: Available in API version 46.0 and later.
```

What is this field purpose? Why it is present?

Does this mean this field is a lookup to another stadnard object?

Comment: This feels like a documentation bug. While it may be internally represented as a reference (e.g. to allow future expansion), the documentation should call it out as what it appears to be. Thanks for this contribution. I'll reach out to the documentation team.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox. When I try to reach SF Support, they are usually very reluctant to update the documentation and never provide even an estimate when the documentation will be updated but too much time is usually spent to explain them why certain thing may be a documentation bug

Answer (score 3):

Not every field with 'reference' type is actually lookup.
For the standard field, only those which end with 'Id' are lookups, with some exceptions.

This field can have several values

`Group|Profile|Regular|Standard|Session`

So it resembles a picklist field.

`Group` value means this permission set represents a `PermissionSetGroup` record, and it has a populated lookup `PermissionSetGroup/PermissionSetGroupId` to `PermissionSetGroup` object record.

If `Type` field has `Group` value, `PermissionSetGroup` lookup should not be empty.

`Profile` value means this permission set represents a `Profile` record and it has a populated lookup `Profile/ProfileId` to `Profile` object record.

If `Type` field has `Session` value, this means this permission set has `Session Activation Required` checkbox checked (set to true).

If `Type` field has `Regular` value, this means this is a custom permission set (which doesn't have `Session Activation Required` checkbox checked) and its `IsCustom` field should have a `true` value.

If `Type` field has `Standard` value, this means this is a standard permission set (which doesn't have `Session Activation Required` checkbox checked) and its `IsCustom` field should have a `false` value.